# How to get Gherkin syntax highlighting for .feature files in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, syntax-highlighting, bdd, specflow, gherkin

There's no highlighting for Feature, Scenario, Given, When, Then, etc. keywords by default. Is there a ready made template out there to enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://github.com/henritersteeg/cuke4vs does exactly this.

Comment: too bad crashes VS2008 when you open a feature file

Answer (score 13):

The recent vesions of [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org) have a built-in syntax highlighting for VS2010.

Comment: make sure you install via the website as opposed to NuGet - some features, for example, run scenario within a .feature file seems only to work if installed this way.

Comment: @Newton: SpecFlow has two parts. The Visual Studio integration has to be installed as MSI, but the runtime (so what is included in your project) can be installed with NuGet.