# how to download Cucumber testing tool for Writing scenarios in gherkin

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, gherkin, cucumberjs

I am looking to download just cucumber software to write the scenarios in Gherkin basically it's for our Product Owner to use for writing the scenarios as part of BDD. When I look online I see I could not find a standalone software for cucumber.  Is there any standalone software which installs cucumber where scenarios can be written in Gherkin language ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275026/are-there-any-non-developer-tools-to-edit-gherkin-files

Comment: You are looking for the functionality that will be provided by Cucumber Pro. Cucumber Pro is a separate product from the company Cucumber that aims to simplify the life of product owners. Check http://cucumber.io for more detaisl if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin which integrates with notepad++. After that, I am able to write feature files with gherkin language.

https://github.com/famished-tiger/gherkin-highlighting

Comment: Found one more plugin - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidy-gherkin/nobemmencanophcnicjhfhnjiimegjeo?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 3):

As part of our current development processes, we also use

> Gherkin basically it's for our Product Owner to use for writing the scenarios as part of BDD

Any relatively modern text editor supports plugins or packages that help you write your requirements in Gherkin. As for us - we use [Atom](https://atom.io/) with the following packs:

- language-gherkin
- gherkin-autocomplete
- gherkin-table-formatter

But there are a lot more for you to customize it according to your own taste.

As a piece of advice I would strongly recommend to *add a linter* check into your CI server's pipeline. We use [gherkin-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gherkin-lint) with great success. Even non techie people get used to it quite quick and produce syntax correct Gherkin for our next Cucumber steps.